# Stripe: Retrieving a customers email address during a charge (Laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I wish to retrieve the customers email address after they have purchased a product, so I can send them a download link.

Here is my processing of the charge.

```
 public function charge()
{
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_key");

    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

    dd(\Stripe\Customer::retrieve($token));

    try {
      $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        "amount" => 10000, // amount in cents, again
        "currency" => "usd",
        "source" => $token,
        "description" => "Example charge"
        ));
    } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
        flashWarning('An error occured');
        return back();
    }

    $data = [];

    Mail::send('emails.download',$data, function($message)
    {
        $message->to(CUSTOMER EMAIL)->subject('thank you for purchasing...');
    });  

}
```

In the bottom half of the method I would like to somehow find the customers email address so I can send them an email.

EDIT: The customers are not users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrive the user's detail or email using Auth then pass to the email with "use" approach

```
// get email first. depends on how you store customer or user email
$email = \Auth::user()->email;

Mail::send('emails.download',$data, function($message) use ($email)
{
    $message->to($email)->subject('thank you for purchasing...');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I forgot to mention that the customers are not users.

Comment: so supposedly you should add an email field in form during charge submission

Comment: Hey thanks for that. I have been using the email field in the submission. However, I am still unsure how to extract the email from the information that is passed through to the back end by stripe.

Comment: you can check the $_POST variable to see all the return fields

Comment: great, maybe can update your post with the answer, might be useful for others

Answer (score 1):

You just access the `email` property off of the `Customer` member:

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($token);

Mail::send('emails.download',$data, function($message) use ($customer)
{
    $message->to($customer->email)->subject('thank you for purchasing...');
});
```

**Side Note**

You can catch all Stripe Exceptions with `Stripe\Error\Base $e` so you can properly return an error message. Have a go:

```
$errors = collect([]);
try {
    //...
} catch (Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
    $errors->push($e->getMessage());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $errors->push($e->getMessage());
}

if ($errors->count() > 0) {
    return back()->withErrors(['message' => implode('. ', $errors->toArray()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I using webhooks you can do it like this

Get the charge object

```
    $charge = $this->webhookCall->payload['data']['object'];
```

Retrieve the email from the charge object array

```
    $email = $charge['billing_details']['email']
```

You can now get use using the email obtained from the charge object as follows

```
    $user = User::where('email', $email)->first();
```